# Modal view does not redisplay?

Tags: ios, xcode, view, modal-dialog

I'm developing an app that needs to pick up a JPEG from a web site on start-up.

The splash screen displays, then the app attempts to get a web address from a file. If the file is missing I open a modal view (as UIModalPresentationFormSheet) that has a text view for the user to type in an address - the address is then saved to a file.

The user taps the OK button, and an attempt is made to get the JPEG. If the address was wrong, or the JPEG is not on the web server, the modal dialog must re-open so the user can change the web address to the correct one.

The splash screen view controller contains these methods:

```
- (void)openAddressDialog
{
    serverView *viewController = [[serverView alloc]init];
    [viewController setServerAddress:[businessLogic serverAddress]];
    [viewController setDelegate:self];
    [viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Interestingly, when I called the openAddressDialog method from the viewDidLoad method the modal view did not appear. I had to move it to the viewDidAppear method. So presumably the view has to be in a particular state before it will entertain modal views.

```
- (void)closeDialog:(UIViewController *)dialogController:(Boolean)actionRequired
{
    // If action required, get the server address from the dialog
    if (actionRequired)
    {
        serverView *viewController = (serverView *)dialogController;   
        NSString *address = [[viewController serverAddress]copy];
        [businessLogic setServerAddress:address];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        if (![logoImage image])
        {
            [logoImage setImage:[businessLogic eventLogo]];

            if (![logoImage image])
            {
                [self openAddressDialog];
            }            
        }

    }
    else
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is the delegate method called back from the modal view when the user has touched OK or Cancel. The actionRequired param indicates that OK was tapped. And if so, the new server address is picked up from the modal view, and the modal view is dismissed. An attempt is made to get the JPEG from the new address (in a business rules class), and if still no file can be found, the first method shown above (openAddressDialog) is called again so the user can correct the address again.

The modal view appears fine the first time, but will not reappear if the user entered the wrong address. Does this have something to do with me attempting to represent the modal view so quickly after dismissing it?

I'm quite new to iPad development, so would appreciate any advice.

One other thing, which demonstrates my inexperience of C++ perhaps, is ... if I declare a private method in the m file, let's call it

```
- (void) methodB
```

and that method calls another private method, let's call it

```
- (void) methodA
```

methodA must be defined earlier in the m file than methodB. If I also want methodA to call methodB I reach an impasse. The only way around that I am aware of is to declare methodB in the h file - which makes it public. How do I code this scenario so the outside world can see neither of the methods?

Answer (score 0):

if use to create nib to serverView then do like this

```
  serverView *viewController = [[serverView alloc]initWithNibName:@"serverView" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Yes, I use init, since the NIB file has the same name as its controller, which works fine elsewhere in my application, and the Apple documentation states that's fine.